# Modifying the timeout of notifications in a firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using the notification function of the firefox SDK to create a firefox extensions. the problem is that after showing the notification it fades away too quickly , is there a way to modify the timeout of the notification ? this is the code i'm using :

```
notifications.notify({
                      title: "notification title",
                      text: " notification text ",
                      data: List[i] ,
                      onClick: function (data) {
                        tabs.open(data);

                      }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control the animation. @canuckistani is half-right: Both the SDK `notifications` and the HTML5 notifications use the same underlying service, the [`nsIAlertsService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/alerts/nsIAlertsService.idl). This service does not allow you to control the duration.

Desktop Firefox does not use system-level services, except for the Metro implementation (yet to be officially released and does not support add-ons anyway IIRC). Instead they use the XUL alert service implementation, which is just [some XUL with some Javascript and some additional CSS](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/alerts/resources/content/).And [some code to open the window](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/alerts/nsXULAlerts.cpp#136).

Depending on some pref, either a hardcoded 4000ms timeout via `setTimeout` will be used, or a 4s CSS animation.

While not convenient, in particular not in an SDK add-on where you do not get a chrome package to open your own XUL windows from, you could copy/paste implement your own fork of the XUL window with controls for the duration, or even override the Firefox default one.
I cannot recall the name right now, but I know there is or was at least one add-on doing exactly that, overriding the built-in implementation and letting the user choose a custom timeout, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The high-level SDK api has not way to control how quickly the notifications go away:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/notifications.html

This implementation in Firefox 22+ relies on the underlying HTML5 notifications api, and in Firefox and Safari specifically the implementations seem to hard-close the amount of time that passes before the notification is closed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Web_Notifications#Creating_a_notification