# How can i add simple link in html5 desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

How can i add simple link (a href) in html5 desktop notification on body section? I try onclick function, but it work's only few seconds. If i try press later the notification just disappear and nothing do. So the best way would be with link. I try that write, but then just print me as text.

```
var notification = new Notification('title', {
icon: '...',
body: '<a href="#">aaa</a>'
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no support for links and other markup in HTML notifications.  The only method to get a clickable link with a notification is to use onclick:

```
function makeNotification() {
    var notification = new Notification('This is a clickable notification', {body: 'Click Me'});

    notification.onclick = function () {
      window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    };
}

function notifyMe() {
    // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }

    // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    makeNotification();
    }

    // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
    // Note, Chrome does not implement the permission static property
    // So we have to check for NOT 'denied' instead of 'default'
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
          // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
          if (permission === "granted") {
            makeNotification();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Mozilla has further documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Firefox has a short duration for notifications compared to Chrome.  There is no way to control how long a notification is visible in Firefox.

Comment: Firstly thanks for respond. :) Notifications works fine, but only few seconds, for example in firefox notification show and automaticaly disappear after few seconds, in chrome notification stay but onclick won't work, again after few seconds wait. Dont know why.

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice that at first as I was testing in Chrome but then after I first posted my answer I tested in Firefox and saw the same thing.  Firefox notifications are designed that way, which is annoying.  Apparently even if you are using the SDK to make an Add-On this can not be changed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456377/modifying-the-timeout-of-notifications-in-a-firefox-extension and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875114

Comment: You could just recreate the notification each time it is closed until the user explicitly closes it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209805/how-do-i-keep-a-notification-open-in-firefox

Comment: @JsonCG: is there a way to redirect to an already opened page in browser?

Answer (score -3):

add  dir : "ltr" in Options

```
    options = {
     dir : "ltr",
    icon: "images/images.jpg",
    body : "hello WOrld"

    }

new Notification("Current Notify",options);
```

Comment: Adding `dir` only sets language direction. `ltr` means from left to right. See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/API/Notification/dir)